# Регулярное выражение для деления дублей

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть текст, внутри которого часто встречаются дубли вида:

> вертикальное направлениевертикальное направление
>
> нагрева инструментовнагрева инструментов

как составить регулярное выражение, чтобы на выходе получить

> вертикальное направление
>
> нагрева инструментов

Пытался модифицировать `(\W|^)(.+)\s\2` , но не вышло.

Comment: Задача ваша некорректна. Если в каждой строке может быть заранее неизвестное количество "дублей", то вряд ли получится решить эту задачу, т.к. "дубли" сливаются, и получается из одного слова два.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярное выражение содержит внутри `\s` - то есть, нужен один пробельный символ между повторами. А примере строк этого пробела нет. Если его убрать, то регулярное выражение будет отрабатывать. Но я бы переписал его так `(.{4,})\1`. 4 там потому что иначе будет находить даже удвоенную букву в словах. Сколько там указать - подбирайте экспериментально.

Comment: Спасибо. Ваше регулярное выражение прекрасно подошло.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, так:

```
\b([-\w ]{2,})\1\b
```